# AttributeError: 'FileDataset' object has no attribute 'ImagePosition'

Tags: python, dicom, pydicom

```
for person in range(0, len(dirs1)):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.join(path, dirs1[person])):
        dcmfiles = [_ for _ in files if _.endswith('.dcm')]
        for dcmfile in dcmfiles:
            dcm_image = pydicom.read_file(os.path.join(root, dcmfile))
            img = dcm_image.pixel_array
            img2 = dcm_image.ImagePosition   # Error in this line
```

for:

```
(0020, 0032) Image Position (Patient) DS: ['-166.000000', '-171.699997', '-207.500000']
```

My problem is that I want the "Image Position (Patient)" structure as an array or one element of it (Like '-207.500000'). 
And when I run the code, this error occurs: the line of  `img2 = dcm_image.ImagePosition` gives `AttributeError: 'FileDataset' object has no attribute 'ImagePosition'`

Comment: Are you sure that `ImagePosition` is an actual property of `dcm_image`? The error is implying that is not the correct name. I think you might need to change the line to be `dcm_image.ImagePositionPatient`.

Comment: Thank you for replying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Image Position (Patient) attribute is, as Karl suggested in his comment, accessible with

```
dmc_image.ImagePositionPatient
```

If the error stil occurs with this attribute it means what the error indicates: your object does not have this attribute.
Dicom states that the keyword for the (0020,0032) tag is ImagePositionPatient, and ImagePosition is actuallly a retired tag (0020, 0030). See [DICOM Data Dictionary](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/pdf/part06.pdf), page 59. So the fact that your object does not have it is probably a good thing.

Comment: I used "dcm_image.ImagePositionPatient" and the error didn't occur.

Answer (score 0):

It has resolved to use the builtin function

```
# Display each DICOM slice
for i, dcm in enumerate(dicom_files):

img = dcm.pixel_array
img2 = dcm.ImagePositionPatient

# height, width, depth = dcm.shape
# print(f"dcm {i + 1} - Size: Height: {height}, Width: {width}, 
Depth: {depth}")

plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
plt.imshow(dcm.pixel_array, cmap='gray')
plt.title(f"Slice {i + 1}")
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```